# determine the flow of the vector field $\textbf{A}=|r|^{-3}\textbf{r}$ out of the cube defined as -L<x<L , -L<y<L , -L<z<L where $\textbf{r}=(x,y,z)$

Tags: vector-analysis, surface-integrals

I want to determine the flow of the vector field $\textbf{A}=|r|^{-3}\textbf{r}$ out of the cube defined as -L<x<L , -L<y<L , -L<z<L where $\textbf{r}=(x,y,z)$

Should I just think of the cube as 6 surfaces and calculate the flow out of each surface by using parametrisation, or is there an easier way to do it? (since this method would give me 6 separate integrals). I also don't understand why the flow is not zero since we are integrating something that is asymmetrical over something that is symmetrical. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: If by flow you mean the surface integral $$\int_{B} \textbf{A} \cdot d\textbf{S}$$ where $B$ denotes the cube and $d\textbf{S}$ the area element, you can think about how to use the divergence theorem to argue that this integral is the same as if you integrated over any sphere centered at the origin.

Comment: @KesavKrishnan but the divergence theorem is not applicable since the vector field is undefined at the origin

Comment: True. But you do not need to integrate at the origin.  You work in the region excluding the origin in which case the divergence theorem is very much applicable. Suppose you look at the sphere with radius less than $L$, and you look at the volume bounded between the sphere and the box, what does the divergence theorem enable you to conclude?